# Add an additional folder onto the maven deploy process

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-deploy-plugin

I currently have this folder structure in my project

```
CTIConnector
|- src
   |-main
      |-java
      |-resources
      |-webapp
```

After using *mvn deploy* the target folder contains a jar, holding the resources folder.
But i would like to also have the webapp folder in the same folder as the jar ( not inside the jar! ). Can someone please tell me how to do this :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the maven-resources-plugin to put things where you want them (it's what runs in the process-resources lifecycle phase anyway: [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)).  Have a look at the [copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) goal for details.  Essentially you'll be looking at something along the lines of this:

```
<project
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/webapp</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    ...
    </build>
</project>
```